# Web Service Implementation - Receive a file from the client

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to implement a web service in Java to receive a file from my client application which is implemented in .Net. But, I am unable to implement the Java web service. I tried a lot to get any example program. But, I didn't get it.

My main objectives is:

1. I will browse and send a file using my .Net client software
2. My Java web service will be able to receive that file
3. After receiving that file, I will do some processing using that file and generate a new file.
4. Now, I will have to return that new file to my .Net client again

Simply,

Input: My web method will have to receive a file
Output: My web method should return a file

Below are my local environment details:

Apache Tomcat 7, Axis 2, Eclipse, JRE 6

Can anybody help me how to write that web method in my Java web service?

Comment: Hi. Yes. As Luca suggested, I tried the code in http://wso2.org/library/3860 link and working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send/receive files as base64 encoded data contained within the XML document or as attachments contained outside the XML document (MTOM).

In wsdl first approach you need to use schema type "base64Binary".

In code first approach you can write:

```
public DataHandler yourMethod(DataHandler input)
or
public byte[] yourMethod(byte[] input)
```

Links:

- http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html
- http://wso2.org/library/3860
- http://wso2.org/library/1675

Comment: Hi Luca,Thanks for your reply. I tried the example in http://wso2.org/library/3860 link and working fine. In our case, our client is developed in C# .Net. Now, we are making the below modifications: 1) at present, its accepting any type of file. but, storing as image file in the local system. It should accept the any type of file (except executable) as usual and store in local system. 2) At present, we can send only one file to the web service. Our Java web service will be able to received one or more files. If I have any doubts, I will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try MTOM with JAX-WS to accept file attachments in a webservice, search in google with these keywords and you should get a lot of hits on how to implement a WS using MTOM and JAX-WS - here are some:
http://isurues.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/how-to-use-mtom-with-axis2-jax-ws-services/
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html